# Possible to deserialize this JSON with objects named as numbers

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is it possible to deserialize this json using JSON.NET?

```
"players": {
        "0": {              
            "success": 1,               
            "name": "xsusususdd"
        },
        "1": {              
            "success": 1,               
            "name": "bleeps"
        },
       ..."n": {
               "success": 1,                
               "name": "bloops"
               }
       }
```

The 3rd party web service that I'm using doesn't return an array but rather an object that is made up of an arbitrary number of nested objects.

I'm starting with something along the lines of:

```
    public class Players
    {
      public Player 0 {get;set;} //cant name the Player 0
      public Player 1 {get;set;} //cant name the Player 1
      public List<Players> players {get;set;} //doesn't work because it isn't being returned as an array
    }


    public class Player
    {          
        public string success { get; set; }         
        public string name { get; set; }        
    }


  var URL = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://webservice");
  Players result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Players>(URL);
```

Comment: one way is to make it as array

Comment: as Array I mean, sorry, just replace "number" with empty string with regex.replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able deserialize as a `Dictionary<string, Player>` (or possibly `<int, Player>`).

Once you have that, you can create a `Players` class from your dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this instead.

```
"players": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "success": 1,               
            "name": "xsusususdd"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,              
            "success": 1,               
            "name": "bleeps"
        },
        {
            "id": n,
            "success": x,
            "name": y
        }
    ]
```

This will create a list with personobjects that you could turn into a dictionary

`Dictionary<string, Player> dictionary = players.ToDictionary(v => v.id, v => v);`

or just a `List<Person>` or what you prefer.

If you need to access them from javascript just use e.g `players[1].name` .